# I don't understand how SAS merge treats columns if you have the same column name in 3 tables with different values

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a REC column that can be found in three tables: GRAV, ATTRI and SIN_TOT. I want to know in the final result of this code, SAS it takes the REC column of which table exactly? knowing that there are different values between the REC column of each table.

```
data plafond_dos;
    
        merge grave (in=a)
              attri (in=b)
              sin_tot (in=c)
        ;
        if a;
        by exer_sin anc_ref cont; 
run;
```

Comment: Last value read in "wins".

Comment: How complex is this merge?  Do those 3 variables uniquely identify the observations in all three of the input datasets? Or do any of them have repeating values?

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lepg/p1phdzzlrc1wi8n1bpigstwt851o.htm#p1gxq53z4oatain1uyy68hgxsuwd) for documentation on this topic, summarizing briefly:

- for the first observation in a `by` group any shared non-by variable will take the value of the *last* dataset (as they appear in the `merge` statement) it was read from.
- all next records within the `by` group will implicitly retain the value from the *first* dataset the variable was read from.

Obviously, it depends on which `by` combinations exist in each of your datasets to determine which of those will be first and last in each group.